# procmail find first 3 upper case chars in subject

Tags: procmail

I am new to procmail and struggling to understand the syntax.

What I want to do is to check the subject line to see if it begins with 3 upper case chars followed by a colon, and if it does, remove the colon from the end and perform and action i.e:

Subject: ABC: Other parts of the subject

```
:0
* $ ^Subject:/^[A-Z]{3}:$/
| /usr/bin/zarafa-dagent -C -P 'Support\\$1' vmail
```

Firstly I'm not sure if my regex is correct, and secondly, despite a lot of googling I can't figure out how to save my search into a variable to use elsewhere, I tried $1 for the first returned variable but that does not appear to work.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can post-process the value of `$MATCH` to trim the colon.

```
:0 D
* ^Subject:[^   ]*\/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]:
{
    :0
    * MATCH ?? ^^\/[A-Z][A-Z][A-Z]
    | /usr/bin/zarafa-dagent -C -P "Support\\$MATCH" vmail
}
```

The first condition captures the three uppercase characters and the colon into `MATCH`.  The second matches this value against three uppercase characters, and captures just that part into the new value for `MATCH`.

As usual, the whitespace inside the brackets after `Subject:` consists of a space and a tab.

Answer (score -1):

OK, solved this, procmail has it's own version of regex:

```
:0 D
* ^Subject:.*\/([A-Z]+[A-Z]+[A-Z]):
| /usr/bin/zarafa-dagent -C -P "Support\\$MATCH" vmail
EXITCODE=$?
```

It does not support the iterator brackets [A-Z]{3} and so you have to repeat the expression.

Also, it is case-insensitive, so you need to add the "D" flag.

Problem is I seem to be unable to remove the colon : from the end.

Comment: The `EXITCODE` assignment doesn't make any sense here; you are assigning it regardless of whether the condition triggered or not.  You should probably add a `w` flag if you genuinely care about the exit code.  Procmail will regard the delivery as failed if the action fails, anyway.

Comment: Also, the `[A-Z]+` is wrong if you really just want to match one uppercase character -- lose the plus quantifier which means "one or more".

Comment: Or if you just want to capture the exit code for your own internal use, don't use the built-in special variable `EXITCODE`.  A good convention is to use lowercase for your own variable names.